# Does SetLength in Delphi Preserve Memory when resizing?

Tags: arrays, delphi

In Delphi, if you use to setlength to **increment** or **decrement** the size of dynamic array, does it preserve the original content of array?

Is it the same for **single** or **multi-dimensional** array?

Up to now, I've always presumed it will keep the old data when the size is enlarged but not sure if it is always like this or I am getting lucky all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Delphi, if you use to `SetLength` to increment or decrement the size of dynamic array, does it preserve the original content of array?

Yes.

> Is it the same for single or multi-dimensional array?

Yes. Remember that a multi-dimensional array is nothing more than an a single-dimensional array whose element type is an array. So what you know for single-dimensional arrays holds for multi-dimensional arrays.

---

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetLength) does cover this:

> For a dynamic array variable, SetLength reallocates the array referenced by S to the given length. Existing elements in the array are preserved and newly allocated space is set to 0 or nil. For multidimensional dynamic arrays, SetLength may take more than one-length parameter (up to the number of array dimensions). Each parameter specifies the number of elements along a particular dimension.